# Vim how to configure complex autocomplete using SuperTab or alternative

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm using SuperTab. By default it allow me autocomplete all early used parts of text. But, I also need to autocomplete some languages or filepathes.

Currently, I can use C-x C-u for omnicomplete, but this is not handy. **Is it possible to configure all autocompletes at tab ?**

For example, I want to autocomplete PHP function name `str_` . If function not exists, then script must use default vim autocomplete.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

**UPDATED**

This is my SuperTab configuration

```
" Supertab
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabCompletionContexts = ['s:ContextText', 's:ContextDiscover']
let g:SuperTabContextTextOmniPrecedence = ['&omnifunc', '&completefunc']
let g:SuperTabContextDiscoverDiscovery =
            \ ["&completefunc:<c-p>", "&omnifunc:<c-x><c-o>"]
```

This use only omnicompletion for php, but not autocomplete another text in current buffer, which only works now when I using `<c-p>` .

When I adding next lines to .vimrc :

```
autocmd FileType *
            \if &omnifunc != '' |
            \call SuperTabChain(&omnifunc, "<c-p>")
            \endif
```

`<c-p>` not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuperTab provides two mechanisms: *context completion* and *completion chaining*, both documented in its [help page](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/master/doc/supertab.txt#L78).

In short, the former can switch to a different (like *omni*) completion if the text before the cursor matches a certain pattern (like a variable or class name). The latter first attempts omnicompletion and falls back to normal insert completion if there were no matches.

Comment: thanks for answer! I have updated my question and add my current config there. Please, help me to understand what's wrong